# How to recursively concatenate columns in SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have created a database which stores some simulations results in this way:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| SimulationID | TypeID | UserID | InputListID | OutputListID |
+--------------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       1      |    1   |    1   |      1      |      11      |
+--------------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       2      |    1   |    1   |      2      |      12      |
+--------------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
|       3      |    1   |    1   |      3      |      13      |
+--------------+--------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

Where InputListID refers to other tables where group of variables are stored. Each simulation could have different number of parameters. If I simply use SELECT connecting the simulations with the variables I get the following table:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| SimulationID | VariableName | VariableValue | VariableUnits |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1      |   Young Mod  |      100      |      GPa      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|       1      |    Poisson   |      0.3      |      NULL     |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|       2      |   Young Mod  |      101      |      GPa      |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|       2      |    Poisson   |      0.25     |      NULL     |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Is it possible to recursively concatenate columns to have something like this:

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+
| SimulationID | Young Mod | Poisson |
+--------------+-----------+---------+
|       1      |    100    |   0.3   |
+--------------+-----------+---------+
|       2      |    101    |   0.25  |
+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

Where the number of columns could change depends on the number of parameters and if units for example are wanted as well?

I am a beginner in SQL, so I apologize in advance if the question seems silly!

Comment: My initial idea was:
1) Get number of parameters per simulation with query
2) For each simulation, select the table/tables for each parameter wanted.
I am not sure exactly how to use recursive in sqlite.

Comment: SQLite does not support that kind of pivot functionality, so it would be easier to solve your problem in your application code.

Comment: You may be able to get some ideas [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788544/how-to-recursively-concatenate-columns-in-sqlite-query)